# How to parse Makefile with Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

It's worked for me. Similarly i have Makefile anf Dockerfile which doesnot have extensions too. How to make comments doxygen readable for Makefile/Dockerfile? For shell scipts which does not recognised by doxygen bu i am using doxygen-bash.sed

Comments should reable by doxygen for Makefile amd Dockerfile.

Comment: .sh files which are parsed by doxygen-bash.sed from gitbub.

Comment: Which doxygen version you are using? What is the link to doxygen-bash.sed at GitHub? Give an example (code) of what is not working for you (i.e. a full example so including the differences between the default doxygen settings and the settings you are using (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile).

Comment: Here is the link for doxygen-bash.sed [link](https://github.com/Anvil/bash-doxygen) and my make file is                                      
 ## Define required macros here
SHELL = /bin/sh

OBJS =  main.o factorial.o hello.o
CFLAG = -Wall -g
CC = gcc
INCLUDE =
LIBS = -lm

hello:${OBJ}
   ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LIBS}

clean:
   -rm -f *.o core *.core

.cpp.o:
   ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES}                                             i just used Makefile as INPUT in doxyfile.

Comment: Please add the information in the question as as it is now it is not very useful. You should also have a look at the settings `EXTENSION_MAPPING`, `FILE_PATTERNS` and `INPUT` / `FILTER_PATTERNS`. Also mention the doxyge version you are using.